# Adding parse sdk to android studio

Tags: java, android

I have to use parse server in my app and i downloaded the sdk file from parse and added the Parse-1.13.0.jar in libs file and then added below code to build.gradle :

compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'

compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'

it makes an error that i cant use + there:

Failed to find: com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+

Failed to find: com.parse:parse-android:1.+

I replace the it with specific version but not working. I tried all answers for similar questions like, removing first statement from codes or removing the .jar file from libs folder, or making new libs folder in src/main/libs directory.
even i tested other past codes like below:

compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')

I want to know for using parse sdk we should have an account in there or not, because i had problem with signing up in parse.com . 
this is my gradle look like :
I really dont know what else should i do for this problem. let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: parse will be closed soon, why you must use that?

Comment: if you use android studio no need to add sdk in lib file..Just write this Dependency in your build.gradle File... `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'

    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0' `

Comment: Ya parse will stop functioning from jan 2017 onwards ,,,,2hycwastectime on it ,,try any other mBaaS

Comment: Which mBaaS do you think is better to use? can you guide me? @HendraWijayaDjiono

Comment: Since parse is going to close soon, maybe better if you use another solutions from here https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseAlternatives
If you insist to use parse, you can download the latest jar. And you even can have your own parse server. Parse is available to deploy to your server